# Is Rhythmbox in active development?

Tags: rhythmbox, development

I see this thrown around a lot: "Rhythmbox is great, but too bad it's no longer being actively developed, which is why I switched to Banshee."

Can someone please clear this up for me, because the way I read that, it tells me the Rhythmbox project has/is going to be abandoned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's still being worked on:
http://git.gnome.org/browse/rhythmbox

It's still a part of Gnome's base apps so for the most part unless Gnome dies, Rhythmbox will still be patching bugs and adding features.

Comment: I'm happy to hear it!